# Kotlin - Debounce Only One Specific Value When Emitting from Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two flows that are being combined to transform the flows into a single flow. One of the flows has a backing data set that emits much faster than the the other.

`Flow A - emits every 200 ms`

`Flow B - emits every ~1s`

The problem I am trying to fix is this one:

```
combine(flowA, flowB) { flowAValue, flowBValue // just booleans
    flowAValue && flowBValue
}.collect {
    if(it) {
       doSomething
    }

}
```

Because Flow A emits extremely quickly, the boolean that's emitted can get cleared rapidly, which means that when flowB emits `true`, flowA already emitted `true` and the state is now `false`.

I've attempted something like:

```
suspend fun main() {
flowA.debounce {
    if (it) {
        1250L
    } else {
        0L
    }
}.collect {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as sometimes the true values aren't emitted - inverting the conditional (so that if(true) = 0L else 1250L) also doesn't work. Basically what I'm looking for is that if flowA is true - hold that value for 1 second before changing values. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I made this use conflated on the 2nd flow, that is drastically faster, so that zipping them will always take the latest value from fastFlow, when slowFlow is finally ready, if you don't use conflated on the 2nd flow, it will always be the first time both emit.

```
fun forFlow() = runTest {
    val slowString = listOf("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
    val slowFlow = flow {
        slowString.forEach {
            delay(100)
            emit(it)
        }
    }

    val fastFlow = flow {
        (1 until 1000).forEach { num ->
            delay(5)
            emit(num)
        }
    }.conflate()

    suspend fun zip() {
        slowFlow.zip(fastFlow) { first, second -> "$first: $second" }
            .collect {
                println(it)
            }
    }

    runBlocking {
        zip()
    }

    println("Done!")
}
```

With Conflated on `fastFlow`:

```
first: 1
second: 15
third: 32
fourth: 49
Done!
```

Without Conflated on `fastFlow`:

```
first: 1
second: 2
third: 3
fourth: 4
Done!
```

Comment: Does this actually work though? I don't want a 1-1 processing, because what can happen is that flowA (the faster flow) emits "true" and the state of flowB might not be true yet. So the `zip` will collect the this pair : true, false. Then when flowB emits true, the zip already processed the true event, and I don't get the expected: true, true pair.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your situation... Do you "drop" B values that aren't true? So you only want the pair when both come through as true?

Comment: Yep - sort of. Basically, I want to make sure that the slower flow has a chance to be "combined" with the faster flow, without the faster flow rapidly changing it state. Essentially, I'd like to "debounce" or "delay" the change from the faster flow from true -> false. I have a very very bad work around right now, where I delay it manually, but it seems like something the coroutine library might already have and I'm probably missing.

Comment: I updated my answer to match what you are looking for